# Clarifications on the assumptions of Poincaré inequality

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, holder-inequality

I am following the proof of the following Poincaré's inequality from the Lieb and Loss textbook

> 8.12 Let $Ω∈\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded, connected open set that has the cone property for some $θ$ and $r.$ Let $1≤p≤∞$, and let $g$ be a function in $L^{p′}(Ω)$, s.t. $\int_{Ω}g=1.$ Let $1 < q < np/(n - p)$ when $p < n,$ $q <\infty$, when $p = n,$ and
> $1 < q <\infty$ when $p > n.$ Then there is a finite number $S>0,$ which depends on $Ω,g,p,q$ such that $$||f-\int_{\Omega}fg|\rvert_{L^q(\Omega)}\leq S||\nabla f|\rvert_{L^p(\Omega)} $$
> $∀f∈W^{1,p}(Ω).$

They begin the proof by assuming $q\geq p$. The explanation for this assumption is given as follows:

> If $q < p$ we can first prove the theorem  for $q = p$ and then use the
> fact that $\Omega$ is bounded and that the $p$ norm  dominates the $q$ norm by
> Hölder's inequality.

What do they mean by this, does the Theorem hold in the case when $q<p$?
The Hölder's inequality states
$$\int_{\Omega}fh=||f|\rvert_{L^p}||h|\rvert_{L^q}, \quad {\rm{for}}\quad \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$$
but I don't see how the $p$ norm dominates the $q$ norm in their argument.
If anyone can please clarify on this I would really appreciate it!

Comment: What they mean is that if $h$ is the function inside the norm on your left-hand side, then $\| h\|_q\leq |\Omega|^{1/q-1/p} \| h\|_p$, then put the $|\Omega|$ term as part of $S$.

Comment: @Jose27 do you mean if $||h||_q\leq |\Omega|^{1/q-1/p}||\nabla h||_p$? (I dont see how you got that)
Then the theorem holds for $q<p$ trivially?

Comment: I didn't put a gradient on the right! My inequality is just Hölder's inequality applied to the product $h\cdot 1_{\Omega}$. Then use the Poincaré inequality with $p=q$ to handle $\| h\|_p$.

Comment: @Jose27 I see that now! So then using the above Poincaré inequality for $p=q$, we get $||h||_q\leq |\Omega|^{1/q-1/p}||h||_p\leq S||\nabla f||_p$, which concludes the proof for $q<p$?

Comment: That's correct.